# How to input a character into an int without breaking the console and giving an error message?

Tags: c++

I want to ask the user to enter an `int` value, and if they enter anything else then it will give them an error message and let them retry. I have that part figured out, but now when the user is to enter an `int` value, it will make them enter it twice. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i;
  char x;

  RETRY:
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  cin >> i;
  if(!(cin >> i)){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    cout << "ERROR! ENTER A NUMBER!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter any character to continue: ";
    cin >> x;
    system("clear");
    goto RETRY;
  }

  cout << "Successful!";
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend either a `while` or `do-while` loop for retrying instead of a `goto`.  Search the internet for "c++ spaghetti code goto".

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for an integer twice.

```
  cin >> i;        // the 1st query here
  if(!(cin >> i)){ // the 2nd query here
```

You should remove `cin >> i;` before the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Just complementing @MikeCAT's answer. Try doing it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i;
  char x;

  RETRY:
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  if(!(cin >> i)){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    cout << "ERROR! ENTER A NUMBER!" << endl;
    cout << "Enter any character to continue: ";
    cin >> x;
    system("clear");
    goto RETRY;
  }

  cout << "Successful!";
```

If you use just the `cin` from inside the if condition your code will behave the way you want. The C++ program will execute the `cin>>i` and then it will check the `if` condition, that's why it works and why you don't have to check it before.

Also, it seems you want to control the terminal as well (by calling `system("clear")`, try searching for libs that provide that functionality (and much much more!), like `ncurses`. You'll be up for a ride using that.

Comment: I just suggested minimal changes to his code that would help him run it and why. using `GOTO` is opinion-based. I don't like it and don't use it, but if the language provides it, I'm in no position to question it.